# Как убрать прыжок от стены в 2D проекте Unity

Tags: unity3d, 2d, controls

Написал небольшой скрипт для прыжка 2D персонажа:

```
public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float JumpForce = 1f;
    public bool IsGrounded;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Jump();
    }
    
    private void Jump()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsGrounded) rb.velocity = Vector2.up * 
        JumpForce;
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground")) IsGrounded = true;
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground")) IsGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

Также поменял материал персонажа, убрав ему трение, чтобы он не цеплялся за стены, но все еще остается возможность при касании стены нажать пробел и прыгнуть от нее. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Измените метод `OnCollisionStay2D` на такой:

```
private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    foreach(var i in collision.contacts)
    {
        if (i.normal.y > 0.8)
        {
            IsGrounded = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь мы берем все точки соприкосновения с другими коллайдерами и, если нормаль по оси Y этой точки больше определенного значения, то мы ставим `IsGrounded` в значение true. Нормаль - вектор, направленный перпендикулярно поверхности, т.е если у нас снизу прямая земля, то нормаль этой земли будет `Vector2(0, 1)`. А нормаль той же стены будет `Vector2(1, 0)`.

Также не следует сравнивать объекты по тэгу, используйте `GetComponent`, т.к. если ошибиться в названии типа, то редактор кода об этом подскажет, а если ошибиться в строке, то ошибка выявит себя только во время игры.

Метод `OnCollisionExit2D` тоже сократите до:

```
private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    IsGrounded = false;
}
```